# Java - Find High and Low Number in an Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the high and low number in an array, but I'm not sure why my codes not working correctly. It's giving me the output of 0 and 56. I understand why it's giving the 0, but where did the 56 come from?

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbs = { '2', '4', '2', '8', '4', '2', '5'};

        int count = 0;
        int low = 0;
        int high = 0;

        while(count < numbs.length)
        {
             if(numbs[count]< low) {
                low = numbs[count];
            }

            if(numbs[count]> high) {
                high = numbs[count];
            }

            count++;   
        }

        System.out.println(low); 
        System.out.println(high);           

    }
}
```

Comment: HINT: if you sort your array first, the highest and lowest numbers will be in very specific locations.

Comment: Yes, definitely not as efficient, but with such a small number of n, the difference is negligible, and with the added benefit of easier to read and maintain code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to start the `low` low enough; currently, you start it at zero - too low to "catch" the lowest element of the array.

There are two ways to deal with this:

- Use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to start the `high` and `low`, or
- Use the initial element of the array to start both `high` and `low`, then process the array starting with the second element.

---

```
int low = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int high = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

---

P.S. You would find strange numbers printed, because you used characters instead of integers:

```
int[] numbs = { 2, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 5};
```

Answer (score 2):

Also.. It is probably printing the ASCII representation... use actual integers (I'm not sure if your usage of chars was intentional).

Answer (score 0):

You should set both the `low` and `high` to the value in the first position of the array.

```
int low = numbs[0];
int high = numbs[0];
```

If the first position is indeed the lowest value it will never be swapped, otherwise it will be swapped with a lower number, the same happen to the highest number.

You want an array of ints that you should declared like such:

```
int[] numbs = {2, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2, 5};
```

You are getting `56` as the highest value because the decimal representation of the char '8' according to the ASCII table is `56`.

Answer (score 0):

You use `char`s instead of `int`s at the array init block, this is immediately converted to `int`s to fit in the `int[]` array, but don't use its actual value, but the *unicode* value, where:  2 = 52 and 8 = 56.

Answer (score 0):

`'8'` is `char` literal, not an `int`. The Java Language Specification [defines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) `char` as follows:

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long [...] and char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units.

If you use a `char` where an `int` is expected, the `char` is implicitly converted to `int`. Since `char` is a numeric type, this will preserve its numeric value, i.e. its UTF-16 [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). The utf-16 code point of `8` is 56.

Treating char as a numeric type can be useful. For instance, we can compute the n-th letter of the alphabet by

```
char nthLetter = (char) `A` + n;
```

or find the numeric value of a digit by

```
if ('0' <= digit && digit <= '9')
    return value = digit - '0';
else
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(digit);
```